# How CUDA box filter works?

Tags: c++, cuda

I have this sample of code that I try to understand it:

```
    __global__ void
d_boxfilter_rgba_x(unsigned int *od, int w, int h, int r)
    {
    float scale = 1.0f / (float)((r << 1) + 1);
    unsigned int y = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (y < h)
        {
        float4 t = make_float4(0.0f);

        for (int x = -r; x <= r; x++)
            {
            t += tex2D(rgbaTex, x, y);
            }

        od[y * w] = rgbaFloatToInt(t * scale);

        for (int x = 1; x < w; x++)
            {
            t += tex2D(rgbaTex, x + r, y);
            t -= tex2D(rgbaTex, x - r - 1, y);
            od[y * w + x] = rgbaFloatToInt(t * scale);
            }
        }
    }

__global__ void
d_boxfilter_rgba_y(unsigned int *id, unsigned int *od, int w, int h, int r)
    {
    unsigned int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    id = &id[x];
    od = &od[x];

    float scale = 1.0f / (float)((r << 1) + 1);

    float4 t;
    // partea din stanga
    t = rgbaIntToFloat(id[0]) * r;

    for (int y = 0; y < (r + 1); y++)
        {
        t += rgbaIntToFloat(id[y*w]);
        }

    od[0] = rgbaFloatToInt(t * scale);

    for (int y = 1; y < (r + 1); y++)
        {
        t += rgbaIntToFloat(id[(y + r) * w]);
        t -= rgbaIntToFloat(id[0]);
        od[y * w] = rgbaFloatToInt(t * scale);
        }

    // main loop
    for (int y = (r + 1); y < (h - r); y++)
        {
        t += rgbaIntToFloat(id[(y + r) * w]);
        t -= rgbaIntToFloat(id[((y - r) * w) - w]);
        od[y * w] = rgbaFloatToInt(t * scale);
        }

    // right side
    for (int y = h - r; y < h; y++)
        {
        t += rgbaIntToFloat(id[(h - 1) * w]);
        t -= rgbaIntToFloat(id[((y - r) * w) - w]);
        od[y * w] = rgbaFloatToInt(t * scale);
        }
    }
```

This should be a box filter with CUDA.
From what I have read this should make an average with a given radius.
But in d_boxfilter_rgba_y make something like this:

```
od[0] = rgbaFloatToInt(t * scale);
```

I don't understand why is used this scale and why are made all that loops when there should be just one. To calculate the value from -r to +r and divide this by a number of pixels.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Is my explanation enough, or do you still have open questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the average of a box with radius 1 (3 values), you do:

```
(box[0] + box[1] + box[2]) / 3 // which is equal to
(box[0] + box[1] + box[2] * 1/3 // which is equal to your scale factor
```

The calculation of scale is:

```
1.0f / (float)((r << 1) + 1); // equal to
1 / ((r * 2) + 1) // equal to
1 / (2r + 1) // 2r because you go to the left and right and +1 for the middle
```

The two for loops are used, because the "sliding window" optimisation is used. First the first box is calculated:

```
for (int x = -r; x <= r; x++)
{
    t += tex2D(rgbaTex, x, y);
}
```

And then for each step to the right, the value right of the box is added and the most left value of the box is removed. That way you can calculate the sum of the box with just 2 operations instead of `2*r + 1` operations.

```
for (int x = 1; x < w; x++)
{
    t += tex2D(rgbaTex, x + r, y);
    t -= tex2D(rgbaTex, x - r - 1, y);
    od[y * w + x] = rgbaFloatToInt(t * scale);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I have some problem like @fhf fhf. The processing for y with d_boxfilter_rgba_y , why isn't some like for x? Ther are some other operation for y. Thank you.

Comment: The same principals are applied in y direction too. I think the reason why there are minor changes hast to do with the padding. Since the box filter result in a slightly smaller image one hast to take actions what to do at the borders and it seems to be different for y.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you very much. It is much clear now.